# Slug имя из поля Title - Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, slug

На данный момент при создании новости мне в ручную приходится вводить url транслитом (Первая новость - pervaya-novost), возможно ли сделать так чтобы это было все при помощи JS ? То есть если я ввожу в поле title слова, то они автоматический переводятся в транслит в поле slug и за место пробелов используют тире?

Comment: Можно, дерзайте!!!!!

Comment: Коль вопрос в разделе Laravel, а не просто javascript... Можно посмотреть ещё и на [Str::slug()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-slug).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function translit(word){
    var answer = '';
    var converter = {
        'а': 'a',    'б': 'b',    'в': 'v',    'г': 'g',    'д': 'd',
        'е': 'e',    'ё': 'e',    'ж': 'zh',   'з': 'z',    'и': 'i',
        'й': 'y',    'к': 'k',    'л': 'l',    'м': 'm',    'н': 'n',
        'о': 'o',    'п': 'p',    'р': 'r',    'с': 's',    'т': 't',
        'у': 'u',    'ф': 'f',    'х': 'h',    'ц': 'c',    'ч': 'ch',
        'ш': 'sh',   'щ': 'sch',  'ь': '',     'ы': 'y',    'ъ': '',
        'э': 'e',    'ю': 'yu',   'я': 'ya',
 
        'А': 'A',    'Б': 'B',    'В': 'V',    'Г': 'G',    'Д': 'D',
        'Е': 'E',    'Ё': 'E',    'Ж': 'Zh',   'З': 'Z',    'И': 'I',
        'Й': 'Y',    'К': 'K',    'Л': 'L',    'М': 'M',    'Н': 'N',
        'О': 'O',    'П': 'P',    'Р': 'R',    'С': 'S',    'Т': 'T',
        'У': 'U',    'Ф': 'F',    'Х': 'H',    'Ц': 'C',    'Ч': 'Ch',
        'Ш': 'Sh',   'Щ': 'Sch',  'Ь': '',     'Ы': 'Y',    'Ъ': '',
        'Э': 'E',    'Ю': 'Yu',   'Я': 'Ya',   ' ': '-'
    };
 
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; ++i ) {
        if (converter[word[i]] == undefined){
            answer += word[i];
        } else {
            answer += converter[word[i]];
        }
    }
 
    return answer;
}

window.onload = function() {
  let title = document.querySelector('.title');
  let text = document.querySelector('.text');
  
  title.addEventListener('input', function() {
    text.value = translit(this.value);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="title">
<input type="text" class="text">
```

https://snipp.ru/jquery/translit-js